# While get state list by country id with ajax, it gives 403 Forbidden error

Tags: ajax, cakephp

I have to display country name and state name with ajax in cakephp 4.3.9

**routes.php:**

```
$builder->connect('/users/getStatesByCountryID/:id', [
                    'controller' => 'Users',
                    'action' => 'getStatesByCountryID',
                ])->setPass(['id']);
```

**signup.php**:

```
        <div class="form-input country"> <label>Country</label>
        <div class="form-select country-select">
        <select name="country_id" required="required" id="country_id">
<option value="1">Afghanistan</option>
<option value="2">Albania</option>
<option value="3">Algeria</option>
<option value="4">American Samoa</option>
<option value="5">Andorra</option>
<option value="6">Angola</option>
<option value="7">Anguilla</option>
<option value="8">Antarctica</option>
</select>
</div></div>

<script>
   
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#country_id').change(function() {
        $('#mydiv').hide();
        var countryId = $(this).val();
        //alert(countryId);
        
        $.ajax({
            url: 'getStatesByCountryID/' + countryId,
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            beforeSend: function(){
                          $('#mydiv').show();
                        },
            success: function(data) {
                $('#mydiv').hide();
                $('#stateid').html('');
                $.each(data.name, function(key, value) {
                    $('#stateid').append('<option value="' + key + '">' + value + '</option>');
                });
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                $('#mydiv').hide();
                console.error("Error fetching states:", textStatus, errorThrown);
            }
        });
        
    });
});
</script>
```

**UsersController.php:**

```
class UsersController extends AppController
{
    public function initialize(): void
    {
        parent::initialize();
    }

    public function beforeFilter(\Cake\Event\EventInterface $event)
    {
        parent::beforeFilter($event);
        $this->Authentication->addUnauthenticatedActions(['login', 'signup', 'verify', 'forgotPassword', 'resetPassword', 'ssesignup', 'loginSse', 'getCentres', 'forgotPasswordSse', 'getStatesByCountryID']);
    }

public function getStatesByCountryID($id){
        $this->request->allowMethod(['get', 'post']);
        $stateList = $this->fetchTable('Countries')->find('list')->select(['id', 'name'])->order(['name' => 'ASC'])->toArray();

        $this->set(compact('stateList'));
    }
}
```

I saw this error in console:

> POST http://localhost/project/users/getStatesByCountryID/6 403
> (Forbidden)
>
> signup:170 Error fetching states: error Forbidden

Any help will be appreciate. Thank you.

Comment: Add a bit of logging into `beforeFilter` there, to see whether it's even reaching that point, or if the error is happening before then? Perhaps some middleware is blocking it before the controller ever even gets instantiated?

Comment: That doesnt need to be POST, GET ajax suffices, if this is not modifying any DB content (which it is not here). Apart from yet, see also https://sandbox.dereuromark.de/sandbox/ajax-examples/chained-dropdowns for examples.

Comment: for a POST, X-CSRF-Token is a requirement but not for a GET request.
In your request, I can't see POST data, perhaps a GET request should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. 403 means url issue. I simply put csrf token and it works.

I put this code: headers : `{'X-CSRF-Token': $('[name="_csrfToken"]').val()},`
and it works.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#country_id').change(function() {
        $('#mydiv').hide();
        var countryId = $(this).val();
        $('#zonespan').html('');
        //alert(countryId);
        if (countryId == '13') {
            $('#zonespan').html(' (Zone wise only)');
        } 
        
        $.ajax({
            url: 'getStatesByCountryID/' + countryId,
            headers : {
              'X-CSRF-Token': $('[name="_csrfToken"]').val()
            },
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            beforeSend: function(){
                          $('#mydiv').show();
                        },
            success: function(data) {
                //console.log(data.name);
                $('#mydiv').hide();
                $('#stateid').html('');
                $('#stateid').append('<option value="">Select State</option>');
                $.each(data.stateList, function(key, value) {
                    //console.log(value);
                    $('#stateid').append('<option value="' + key + '">' + value + '</option>');
                });
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                $('#mydiv').hide();
                console.error("Error fetching states:", textStatus, errorThrown);
            }
        });
        
    });
```